# PHP artisan migrate doesen't works even fresh why?

Tags: php, laravel

`php artisan migrate:fresh` doesn't work. Why doesn't string address appear in my database. I follow a laravel tutorial and it still didn't work as I wanted.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('address'); // <- here
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('profiles');
    }
}
```

[image: Picture 1]

Comment: What do you want to happen? What is desired output? have you cleared cache and tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache with `php artisan cache:clear`.
If that doesn't work you can manually add the column in phpmyadmin.
If you don't mind losing data try `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to add column in a preexistent table, if that is the case you could do it with a migrate that modifies (not create) the table, in you case you can do something like this :

```php
class AddAddressToProfiles extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // is a good practice use data lenght and decorators in migration consider do "->default(null)->nullable()" etc. etc.
            $table->string('address', 255);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('address');
        });
    }
}
```